# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV, I am getting Assertion failed error when I run a template matching code. The error message is given below

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, 
file /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/conda_1485299292920/work/opencv-
3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 9748
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "opencv_basics.py", line 6, in <module>
   img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/travis/miniconda/conda-
bld/conda_1485299292920/work/opencv-
3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9748: error: (-215) scn == 3 || 
scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

This the code I'm trying to run.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Template Matching
img_rgb = cv2.imread('opencv-template-matching-python-tutorial.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.imread('opencv-template-for-matching.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Detected',img_rgb)
```

The gdrive folder link for the images used is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B717wCPy7sE8SFdzNUp0U2l2U00)

I tried reinstalling opencv3 but it is vain. 
I'm using python 3.5 and OpenCV 3.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice always that you load a resource, like read an image, check if the resource was actually loaded. In that case, you should to check:

```
img_bgr = cv2.imread('opencv-template-matching-python-tutorial.jpg')
if img_bgr is not None
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Note: Since in OpenCV by default the color space model is BGR (not RGB) I just renamed your img_rgb variable to img_bgr.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure the images are on the same folder as the code.**

I know, it's stupid and probably you had already checked that. I had the same exact problem. The answer seems stupid but it worked for me. I assume you have already figured it out. But for the sake of no one repeating it I will leave this here.

From what I have found, if the problem persists you should probably search for "imread not loading images properly" because that's the root of this error.

---

*P.S. I too am following the same tutorial! Keep learning! And for those uninitiated: https://pythonprogramming.net/template-matching-python-opencv-tutorial/*

Comment: Thank you, Captain.